# Flexbox item refusing to grow

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm trying to make a calculator website ([codesandbox here](https://codesandbox.io/s/stoic-shtern-jnw75k)). I have a problem where the decimal button on the calculator is not growing; for some reason it's smushed.

I'm using flexbox to display and align all the rows and buttons on the calculator. What I want is the zero button to be twice as big as the other number buttons. I want the operator buttons (=, +, etc.) to be aligned with each other as well.

I've tried messing around with `width` and `flex` css properties on my classes to no avail. I'm sure the solution is simple but for some reason it's eluding me.

Thank you for your time reading this. I appreciate any help you can give me.

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to just set the widths in % instead of grow/shrink, since the layout is that rigid? Maybe even use CSS grid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The flex-grow CSS property sets the flex grow factor of a flex item's main size.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-grow

```
.decimal-button,
.equals-button {
  flex: 1;
}

.zero-button {
  flex: 2;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much :). This solution has a slight misalignment issue with the 0 and decimal point buttons, but using `flex: 2.02` on .zero-button seems to fix it.